# Laptop charger: is 100-250V input an acceptable replacement for a 100-240V charger?

Tags: voltage, charger

very simple question.

A friends laptop charger is broken, so we're looking at getting a new one.

The old one says - input 100-240V 50-60hz 1.5A
output 19V 4.74A

Looking online, there are a very similar charger, but the specs say input 100-250V 50-60hz 1.5A.

Would this still work fine?

Comment: I don't think this question deserved any downvotes... Just my opinion...

Comment: I agree, this question does seem a bit, off I guess, but it is still a valid question, and can be further opened by, as an example, why there is a voltage difference if 10v between the power supplies, and how does it impact the outputs.

Comment: @CountZero - This question is egregiously off-topic.  This site is not about buying consumer electronics or reading their labels, it's about designing those products.  Anyone reading the FAQ or watching the front page would know this.  Because the author didn't do this research, a downvote is deserved.  In fact, the site [automatically adds another downvote when the question is closed as 'off topic'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84978/146495).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is the only difference it should work just fine.

What 100-250V is telling you is that it will work with any input voltage between 100 volts and 250 volts. This is a wider range than your old charger that was only rated to 240 volts.

Answer (score 3):

If the output is still exactly 19V and 4.74A or more A's, then it is OK.

I think the best option is to buy an original replacement item, because you can hardly know the quality level of those noname power supplies / chargers.

Answer (score 2):

It should work just fine, as the other OPs said before. The difference is probably that your old unit was manufactured before the voltage on `220 V` networks (e.g. Europe) was stepped up to `230 V`. Then, to keep the safety margin of `20 V`, the unit needed to be redesigned for max. `250 V`.

The specified current at the output can be larger than with the old one, because the load (your friend's laptop) will draw anyway as much current as it needs. (Usually below the specified `4.74 A`, depending on usage: charging or not, using just a word processor or playing a computationally intensive 3D FPS over the net, etc.) It just shouldn't be less than the original value.

So as a remark: theoretically at least, more amps is better. on the other hand, too much of it will mean that the supply is never fully utilized and it will be less efficient. But that's a different story, with more complex implications, you needn't worry about. `:)`